# Convert a PNG image into data which can be sent through NSSockets

Tags: cocoa, http, sockets

I have to send a PNG image through Cocoa Sockets (AsyncSockets) and I can't manage to send it correctly, Firefox tells me the image is corrupted and Chrome doesn't shows anything. I use this code:

```
content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP/1.1 %@\nContent-Type: %@\n\n\n ", responseCode, contententType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[sock writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
[sock writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:[content bytes] length:[content length]] withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

As you can see I first send the headers and then I send the NSData bytes & length, but I can't manage to get the PNG image correctly! What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but the newlines are wrong. They should be \r\n.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö: you should post this as an answer. I believe CRLF *is* required in the header.

Comment: There is no reason for -dataWithBytes:... just use content as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line endings are wrong, they should be \r\n, not just \n.